# Regarding delete route

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have written the below route for deleting a particular exam from the list of exams.

```
Router.get('/get_exam_code_delete', auth.checkLogin, function(req , res){ 

res.render('delete'); 
}); 

Router.post('/exam_code/delete', auth.checkLogin, function(req , res){ 

examModel.remove({'exam_code':req.params.exam_code},function(err , result){ 

if(err) 
res.send(err); 
else{ 

res.send(result) 
              } 
}); 
});
```

The result shows ok .

But when I go back and view the list of exams page , the row entry is still there for that exam_code.

Actually, I want my delete route to do the below task:

Whenever the delete route is called and the corresponding exam with a particular exam_code is deleted, the corresponding entry should be deleted from the
list of exams page. But it is not happening here.

Can anyone please help here?

Comment: What is examModel here?

Comment: Here examModel is the model name where all the fields related to details of exam are stored. Ex: exam name , exam code etc.